# Yii2: Undefined variable if $model = Model::find()->all(); is not specified in view

Tags: php, yii2

I have a view where I need to show both table of current records and search within the table. The problem is, that after a search action the table still shows all records, despite URL shows searching parameters. I suppose, that is because all records specified in model (`$posts = Post::find()->all();`).

But if I remove that string, I get an exception "Undefined variable: posts".
How can it be fixed?

Model:

```
class Post extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'post';
    }

    public $upload;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['desc'], 'required'],
            [['desc'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['upload'], 'file'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionSearch()
    {

        if (Yii::$app->request->get()){
            $search = Yii::$app->request->get('search');
            $query = Post::find()->where(['like', 'desc', $search]);

            return $this->render('search', compact('query', 'search'));
        } else {
            $files = Post::find()->all();

            return $this->render('search', ['files' => $files]);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\Post;

$this->title = 'Search';

$posts = Post::find()->all();
?>

<div class="site-search card border-secondary">
    <div class="card-header"><h3><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h3></div>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'action' => ['search'],
            'method' => 'get',
    ]) ?>
    <div class="body-content card-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?= Html::textInput('search','', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-4">Name</th>
                    <th class="col-md-6">Description</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?foreach ($posts as $post):?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden"><?=$post->id?></td>
                    <td><?=$post->file?></td>
                    <td><?=$post->desc?></td>
                    <td><?= Html::a('Download', ['download', 'id'=>$post->id]) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$posts` value to your view:

```
public function actionSearch() {
    if (Yii::$app->request->get('search')){
        $search = Yii::$app->request->get('search');
        $posts = Post::find()->where(['like', 'desc', $search])->all();
    } else {
        $posts = Post::find()->all();
    }

    return $this->render('search', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

Then you can remove `$posts = Post::find()->all();` from your view.

Comment: Even if $posts are passed to the view, there is still an exception with `$posts = Post::find()->all();` not specified in the view.

Comment: @Cellofun can you please try to add in view long open php tag? at the moment you are using short one `<?` replace with `<?php foreach` and the same in `endforeach`, not completely sure, but can be that because the above code is correct

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai, thank you for your advise! But even with long php tag there is still an exception

Comment: My bad! I just replaced the `['posts' => $posts]`. After removing `return $this->render('search', compact('query', 'search'));` everything went fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In view your refer to $posts  but in actionSearch you use $files  so 
In your action  change the $files in $posts

```
  public function actionSearch()
  {

      if (Yii::$app->request->get()){
          $search = Yii::$app->request->get('search');
          $posts= Post::find()->where(['like', 'desc', $search]);

          return $this->render('search', compact('query', 'search'));
      } else {
          $posts = Post::find()->all();

          return $this->render('search', ['posts' => $posts]);
      }
  }
```

and then in view  remove the  $postes

```
  $this->title = 'Search';

  //$posts = Post::find()->all();
  ?>
```

Comment: I did just as you have suggested, but still I get an exception without `$posts = Post::find()->all();` in my view.